# set focus on textbox on a button click in mvc3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have made a form in MVC and have included tabs. So I want to redirect to a text on a button lcik which is not in the default tab. So how can I do that

Comment: You need to do it with JavaScript on the client side. But for the how we need more info. e.g. How have you included tabs? Can you post some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

Write some jquery:

```
$('#buttonId').click(function(){
    $('#textboxtofocusId').focus();
})
```